# accessing a MovieClip's property within a Sprite (and vice-versa)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

test.fla's document class is Test.as
test.fla's library has two MovieClips ThingMovieClip and Thing2MovieClip

I tried accessing the Thing.as public var thingState's property;
directly,
using something called Casting (??),
assigning an instance name,
but something that seemed so simple doesn't work,
I commented the errors I got next to each way I tried,

conversely how would I access the MovieClip Thing2MovieClip from Thing.as (which is a child of Test.as because that's where it's instantiated), it just doesn't recognise an object of its parent exists, here are the 2 classes:

package com.hello.test.test
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    public var container:Sprite;        
    public var thing:Thing; // a Class that extends Sprite that creates a thingGraphic:ThingMovieClip in it from test.fla library
    public var thing2Graphic:Thing2MovieClip; // base class is MovieClip, in test.fla library

    public function Test()
    {           
        container = new Sprite();
        addChild(container);            

        thing = new Thing();
        container.addChild(thing);

        thing2Graphic = new Thing2MovieClip();
        addChild(thing2Graphic);  // adds a Thing2 to stage I presume

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function update(e:Event):void
    {
        //  trace(container.thing.thingState);              // Access of possibly undefined property thing through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite
        if(container.thing.thingState == container.thing.thingState.OFF_)
        {
            trace("container.thing.thingState = OFF_");
        }  //1119:Access of possibly undefined property thing through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite
        //  trace(container.MovieClip(thing).thingState);     //1061: Call to a possibly undefined method MovieClip through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite
        //  var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildByName(thing);  //Implicit coercion of a value type com.hello.test.test:Thing to an unrelated type String
        //  trace(child);
    }
}
```

}

package com.hello.test.test
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
public class Thing extends Sprite
{
    public var thingGraphic:ThingMovieClip;
    public static const ON_:String = "on_";
    public static const OFF_:String = "off_";
    public var thingState:String;

    public function Thing()
    {
        thingState = OFF_;
        buttonMode = true;
        useHandCursor = true;

        thingGraphic = new ThingMovieClip();
        thingGraphic.stop();
        addChild(thingGraphic);

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePressed, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function mousePressed(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("pressed");
        thingState = ON_;
        trace("thingState " +thingState);
        thingGraphic.play();

        //this.parent.thing2Graphic.play();     // how can I access the thing2 at Test.as (this Class's parent)
        // 1119: Access of possibly undefined property thing2 through a reference with static tpe flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function mouseReleased(e:MouseEvent):void
    {   
        thingState = OFF_;
        trace("thingState " +thingState);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);
        thingGraphic.stop();
    }

    public function update():void
    {
        trace("updated");
    }   
}
```

}

I think i'm missing some basic but fundemental understanding of ActionScript 3 and I have no other knowledge of other scripting/programming languages either.
when I follow tutorials exactly they seem simple enough, but then start applying what I think is logical usage then it throws up errors..
any recommendations of books for a simple understanding, i.e technical but in normal language of AS3, since I have Foundation AS3.0 Animation, Making Things Move (great book, keeps to concepts; wish there was a book like this about AS3 itself) and The Essential Guide to Flash Games (very technical, can barely follow as-is)??

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Test.as, just use the member variables:

```
trace (thing.thingState);
```

In your Thing.as, cast the parent.parent object (parent of the container!) to `Test`:

```
var p:Test = parent.parent as Test;
p.thing2Graphic.play();
```

Comment: thanks a lot(!!) I tried reshuffling that to Test(parent.parent).thing2Graphic.play(); also works, I need to read up on (and understand) casting and why it's needed, since i'd have thought from your answer that, parent.parent.thing2Graphic.play(); would work, thanks again,

Comment: `parent.parent` will yield a `DisplayObject`. When working with tougher Actionscript, you really need to keep track of your typing. Syntax highlighting (the stuff that pops up when you type "thing.", etc) along with Adobe's documentation (highlight a blue keyword and hit f1 for specific help) will go a long way towards keeping track of your datatypes.

Comment: both great answers but only 1 tick, found the green tick it is, oke done!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of your commented errors.

1. Instead of `container.thing.prop`, try accessing the property through `thing.prop`.
2. Instead of `container.MovieClip(thing)`, try `var newThing = thing as MovieClip`.
3. `getChildByName` expects a `String` (think instance names which also work). You're feeding it a custom class that extends the `Sprite` class.
4. Add the `MOUSE_DOWN` listener inside the parent class to the `thing` variable.

```
//(inside Test.as)

thing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousePressed, false, 0, true);

private function mousePressed(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    thing2Graphic.play();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much(!!) I'd have thought that to access thing's property that I deliberately put into the container Sprite, would require going through that, your answer perfectly but the 'logic' is making me paranoid!!

Comment: When traversing through nested library items, you do need to use the `parent.child` syntax to access them. However, since you're instantiating (creating) a new `Thing`, you just need to refer to the variable you used while creating it.

Comment: 4. originally I was going to have everything inside Test.as, to keep it simple, then decided thing:Thing needed a few properties so tried putting everything concerning it inside the class,                                                                so I learnt that something instantiated in that class can be called directly by it's instance name even if after it has been parented or nested in something else, thanks for helping a newbie!!